# Does Visual studio solution open in visual studio mac?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I want to know, if i send a solution folder (it's written in visual studio C#) ,  can you open the solution in visual studio for mac?

The project developed by in a visual studio 2017,  then I need open in visual studio for mac version.

The projects could be : console, windows form, wpf, mvc projects.

Comment: VS4M does not support every project type that VS4W does so it depends upon the types of projects that the solution contains... Do you have a list of project types (or project type guids)?

Comment: Tur projects could be Console app, win form, wpf and Asp.net mvc. @SushiHangover

Comment: You did not specific the language, but if that console app is C#/F# based, then yes it would open. WPF-based apps are not supported on macOS and are not supported within VS4M, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-mac

Visual Studio 2017 for Mac contains many new and exciting features and IDE productivity enhancements to support cross-platform desktop app development, cross-platform mobile development, Azure development, web and cloud development, and more.